# Editted Theme Files Get Updated/Reverted Every So Often

Tags: php, themes

I have editted my WordPress theme php files; I am using the Enigma theme and I have editted files such as;

- front-page.php
- home-slideshow.php

Everything works fine but every so often these files either get updated or reverted back to their old versions and obviously my site breaks. I've made simple changes to the files such as url escape certain strings from the database and use get_template_part() on the front page to retrieve my custom PHP files. The funny thing is that I have turned off automatic updates of themes (I turned it off through the interface) but maybe its still turned on or there is something else causing the files to revert/change.

Do you know what could cause these files to change? How can I programmatically disable theme updates? Whats the proper procedure to edit theme files and ensure they dont get overwritten? Should I copy the enigma theme and create a new folder with a new theme name?

Comment: it's not clear why theme files would get reverted or updated, but the proper way to edit a theme is to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using third party themes then always create the child theme for the third party theme because they always do changes and update the theme version so it will over write all your customization in your theme.

You can get help how to create child theme here https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes